# Why doesn't my system boot from the installation disk?

Tags: installation, 12.10, livedvd

In BIOS, I have set the CD drive as a priority boot drive. The DVD boots fine on my other desktop (Windows 7). My PC is a bit old, is this the problem? The DVD drive tries to boot but after a while, it boots to the `C:/` drive.

Comment: Are you sure you've got a CD disk, not a DVD? Ubuntu 12.10 does not fit on a CD, as far as I know. Which would explain why your "a bit old" machine does not boot from it (assuming that it has a CD drive).

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem:

1. Boot in Windows 7;
2. Insert the Ubuntu CD;
3. When the "Autoplay" pops out click next;
4. Now click "Help me to boot" and next;
5. Wait while the boot entry is installed;
6. Click "Reboot Now" and then click "Finish";
7. When the boot manager appears use the arrows to select "Ubuntu" and press enter;
8. Wait;
9. Install Ubuntu.